# How get gridster in stop resize method?

Tags: angularjs, gridster

How get gridster ? `$(".gridster ul").gridster()` is undefiened

```
vm.gridsterOpts = {
            resizable: {
                enabled: true,
                start: function (event, $element, widget) { },
                resize: function (event, $element, widget) { },
                stop: function (event, $element, widget) {
                    // how get gridster ? $(".gridster ul").gridster() is undefiened
                    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
                    var newDimensions = gridster.serialize();

                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help you, but you can get some info on the gridster element using the widget parameter of your function.

There's the (row, col, sizeX, sizeY) which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug pointer from browser in stop method. Then type "this" in console. Gridster object is the callee of this function hence youll get it.
Or
You can get gridster object explicitly like this -

```js
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").data()
```

What you are writing will re-initialize gridster